# Permanent & Safe Powering of Raspberry Pi in Confined Space

Tags: pi-2, power, safety

I have a small project that involves the automation of the lights in a room using a Raspberry Pi and a set of four relays. All of the software and hardware is operational, and it is ready to be installed.

However, the space that the Pi will be stored in is rather small, and I am aware of the heat that standard USB adapters can generate. Using one of these in such an environment seems rather hazardous, and I am looking for another way to convert the 230 V mains power down to a level that suitable for the Raspberry Pi.

How am I able to do this while maintaining high safety standards?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the efficiency specs on the converter (higher is better) and get the lowest power rating that will do the job. Both of those will reduce the waste heat produced by the power supply.

Is there any chance of either venting the space where the project is installed or putting the power supply outside of the space in free air?

Comment: Ventilation would be unlikely in this situation, but even so, would a high efficiency converter be safe enough without it?

Comment: Without knowing more about the application it really isn't possible to say anything specific. "Good" power supplies will have heat dissipation specs as well as temperature limits. You could add a temperature sensor on the Pi and do some testing.

Comment: Have you thought of PoE (which runs at 48V (SELV)) and moves your need to convert from 230V AC away from where your RPi is located.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have actually made a test run and measured an unacceptably high temperature, I think you are worrying over a hypothetical issue. Power adapters are made to run without any kind of active cooling and their internal components are already enclosed in a plastic case. Enclosing them in another case will increase the temperature somewhat, but not nearly as much as e.g. having direct sunlight on the adapter, or using it next to a room heater.

Avoid putting heat insulating materials (such as foam) around the adapter and the Pi, and you'll be fine. Dismount your installation and measure the temperature after a few hours if you want to be sure.

And BTW, power adapters with higher ratings tend to have higher safety margins for temperature and better heat dissipation, so I wouldn't pick one with the lowest power rating. Of course, you still want to pick an efficient one; if your adapter gets hot by running the Pi on your desk, you'll want to pick a different one to be used in a closed space.